# How to receive a FormData that uploaded by ajax in ActionSupport file in Struts2?

Tags: ajax, struts2, form-data

I'm trying to send and receive a file using ajax and Struts2. Here is my code:

**JSP**

```
<span class="input-group-btn"> 
     <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"> Browse 
     <input id="file" type="file" accept="application/x-pkcs12">
</span>
```

**JS**

```
var file = $('#filepath')[0].files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('filepassword', filepassword);

$.ajax({
    url : 'FileAction',
    type : 'POST',
    async : true,
    data : formData,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) {
        if (data.jsonResponse.status== 'OK') {
            message("Send file successfull.");
        }
});
```

}

**struts.xml**

```
    <action name = "FileAction" class="package.FileActionSupport" 
    method = "ReceiveFile">
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">p12</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result type="json">
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
            <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
            <param name="excludeProperties"></param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

But, In Action Support file, I don't know how to receive a variable with type `FormData`. I found an JSP/Servlet example receive FormData:

```
List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                            (FileItemFactory) new DiskFileItemFactory())
                                    .parseRequest(request); // HttpServletRequest
byte[] ks = null;
for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
    if (!item.isFormField()) {
        if (item.getContentType().startsWith("application/x-pkcs12")) {
            ks = item.get();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I tried to get `HttpServletRequest` in action support file with

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

and tried again with above code but it doesn't work.
Thank for your help.

**UPDATE**

```
var file = $('#filepath')[0].files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file); (1)
formData.append('filepassword', filepassword);
```

Follow [this](https://gist.github.com/ronsc/c58ae8c5566a897cc9ad) guide,I used `MultiPartRequestWrapper` and I could get FormData in Action File. But there is a problem. My file have a password and I need it in action file too (`filepassword`) . But I just get content of file and file name (`file`)

Comment: Why did you reference fileUpload interceptor?

Comment: In FormData, I want to upload a p12 file. Show I follow this guide. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_file_uploads.htm

Comment: You can't receive form data it's not sent to the action.